# Pandas - Drop row from list of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [100, 101, 134, 139, 192],
               'Name': ['Tom', 'Dave', 'Steve', 'Bob', 'Jim']})
```

and a list of values:

```
id_list = [100, 139]
```

I want to drop the rows from my dataframe if the 'ID' column == one of the values in my id_list.

The desired output is...

```
    ID   Name
1  101   Dave
2  134  Steve
4  192    Jim
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.isin()` for the `ID` series preceded with `~`. Essentialy this works like *"Not in"*:

```
output_df = df[~df['ID'].isin(id_list)]
```

Output:

```
    ID  Name
1   101 Dave
2   134 Steve
4   192 Jim
```

Comment: so easy. I have not seen the ~ before. Thank you!